# Pass Python object directly to C++ program without using subprocess

Tags: python, c++

I have a C++ program that, through the terminal, takes a text file as input and produces another text file. I'm executing this program from a Python script which first produces said text string, stores it to a file, runs the C++ program as a subprocess with the created file as input and parses the output text file back into a Python object.

Is it possible to do this without using a subprocess call? In other words: is it possible to avoid the reading and writing and just run the C++ program inside the Python environment with the text-string as input and then capture the output, again inside the Python environment?

For code I refer to the function `community_detection_multiplex` in [this IPython notebook](https://github.com/ulfaslak/InfomapSensibleDTU/blob/master/preproc.ipynb).

Comment: Do you have a C++ parser/interpreter written in Python? If yes, great. Otherwise, no.

Comment: spawning a subprocess isn't really a big deal is it? You could send the input/collect output via stdin/stdout pipe redirects if you want to avoid the security risk of the file.

Comment: @RichardHodges how would I pass the string to the C++ program from Python if it were never stored as a file?

Comment: @UlfAslak with a pipe. The subordinate program could just read data from stdin and write to stdout. These would map to the python program's pipe (which it would create).

Comment: @UlfAslak lots of info here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline

Comment: @RichardHodges Thanks! That's just what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ctypes.html).
It requires the C++ function to be wrapped with `extern "c"` and compiled as C code.

Say your C++ function looks like that:

```
char* changeString(char* someString)
{
    // do something with your string
    return someString;
}
```

You can call it from python like that:

```
import ctypes as ct

yourString = "somestring"
yourDLL = ct.CDLL("path/to/dll") # assign the dll to a variable
cppFunc = yourDLL.changeString # assign the cpp func to a variable
cppFunc.restype = ct.c_char_p # set the return type to a string
returnedString = cppfunc(yourString.encode('ascii')).decode()
```

Now `returnedString` will have the processed string.

Comment: Ideally I would want the file to not be stored, and it seems that your solution does this?

Comment: My solution calls a C++ function and pass a string to it. If you want to open a file in Python and pass it (while open) to C++, then this is not the right solution for you.

Comment: as I understand this solution has the string stored as a file

Comment: `yourPathToFile` is a string variable contains a path to a file (ideally, I would use the `os.path` module to create a path string). You can do `with open(yourPathToFile) as f:` and read the file in python. In the solution I posted, it is expected that the c++ function will open the file within itself.

Comment: I'm sorry I must not have explained it well enough. The python script generates the string which should be processed by the C++ program. That's why I want to avoid saving any files.